# How to occupy the space of a linear gradient with a view flex in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, view, flexbox, linear-gradients

I have an issue with LinearGradient : when I use it, I can't use flex in my view to distribute the space (I want to assign square to différents part of my project). It only allows me to use the space if I use something inside the View (ex: a ) .
Any idea?
Here is my code :

```
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 11,
            backgroundColor: "green",
          }}
        >
          <LinearGradient
            colors={["#42B189", "#88CDB8", "#2FB59B", "#88CDB8", "#42B189"]}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.textg}>TOOLBOX</Text>
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "red",
                flexDirection: "column",
              }}
            >
              <View
                style={{
                  flex: 10,
                  backgroundColor: "violet",
                }}
              >
                <Text>Trying</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </LinearGradient>
        </View>
```

```
  textg: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: "600",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#FFFFFF",
  },
```